# Rails way of sum query with join and calculation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sum

I have the following query

```
@entity = Unit.joins(:item).select('SUM((items.entity/items.amount*units.amount)) AS entity')
```

How can this be done in a more rails like way?

Comment: This gem https://github.com/ernie/squeel can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Unit.joins(:item).sum('items.entity/items.amount*units.amount')
```

Comment: For some reason this only provides rounded values, no decimal. eg. 19 instead of 19.5

Comment: That's strange. Can you share the output of: select * from units left join items;